# Best way of monitoring jndi datasources on Tomcat servers

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

We have a monitoring app (Java Spring app) that performs a bunch of tests for various web services, web apps, databases, etc. and notifies us when things have gone wrong.

The apps we're monitoring are Java web apps (written in Vaadin), and occasionally they will lose their database connection and we don't find out until a user tries to do something that hits the database and it fails.

The apps are running on Tomcat servers, using jndi -- what are some lightweight/easy to implement options for programmatically figuring out whether our Tomcat servers still have good connections to their databases?

Keep in mind that the monitoring app as well as the other apps are all running on different Tomcat servers on different boxes.

Unfortunately, there are no web services that we can call for these apps, otherwise we would just do that.

Comment: If you use a connection pool the problem should disappear.

Comment: Why don't you just poll the same thing that the users do when it blows up?

Comment: If that is really really not possible (and I find it unlikely that something deployed on tomcat doesn't have a listening socket for clients) then have a look at JMX (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html) noting that you dont need to use ant to query the JMX components on tomcat. There used to be some way of doing it from the command line otherwise try this: http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm (or just use the ant tasks)